# C# web form submitted data could not insert sql database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I am just a beginner trying to follow the tutorial. I did search for the closest questions, tried several of them. None of them works for me. I just need some clues where it possible goes wrong. thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Company
{
    public partial class ContactUs : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void update(string FirstName, string LastName, string EmailAddress, string MobileNumber, string category, string message)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            string sql = "INSERT INTO ContactInformation (GUID,FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Number, Category, Message) VALUES "
                        + " (@GUID,@FirstName,@LastName,@EmailAddress,@Number,@category,@message)";

              Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
              string guidString = guid.ToString();

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                SqlParameter[] p = new SqlParameter[7];
                p[0] = new SqlParameter("@GUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,50);
                p[1] = new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
                p[2] = new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
                p[3] = new SqlParameter("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
                p[4] = new SqlParameter("@Number", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
                p[5] = new SqlParameter("@Category", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
                p[6] = new SqlParameter("@Message", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
                p[0].Value = guid;
                p[1].Value = FirstName;
                p[2].Value = LastName;
                p[3].Value = EmailAddress;
                p[4].Value = MobileNumber;
                p[5].Value = category;
                p[6].Value = message;

                for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p[i]);
                }
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Insert Error:";
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ContactInformation"].ConnectionString;
        }
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) 
            {
                Validate();
                update(txtFirstName.Text,
                                  txtLastName.Text,
                                  txtEmail.Text,
                                  txtNumber.Text,
                                  DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text,
                                  txtMessage.Text);
                Response.Write("Record was successfully added!");
                //ClearForm(Page);
            }
        }
        public static void ClearForm(Control Parent)
        {
            if (Parent is TextBox)
            { (Parent as TextBox).Text = string.Empty; }
            else
            {
                foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls)
                    ClearForm(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the connection string is in the web.config file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ContactInformation" connectionString="datasource=database;initial catalog=ContactInformation;Integrated Security=SSPI;userid=xxx;password=xxx;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I deployed the website on my local machine and try to test it on Internet Explorer.And on the other side, I open the database management tools,the table is still empty.

Comment: Hi @MethodMan Sorry I am not familiar with posting. I just edited my code. I receive no errors for the code. I just could not insert any data to the database.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code line by line with the debugger? Did it follow the path through the code that you expected?

Comment: I think that you should look at how to properly create parameters also when you step through the code you should be able to evaluate and and all parameter values. also put a breakpoint on this line and see if it hits this line `string msg = "Insert Error:";1` you should also wrap your Sql Objects around a `using() {}` you are not disposing of all of the created objects

Comment: What does “could not insert” mean? Are you getting an error? [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39233746/edit) your post and add the error message. Or did it not throw an error but you think the data wasn't inserted? What makes you think that?

Comment: You have a check for not postback in your button click. Pretty sure that's gonna be true; button click will be a postback. !IsPostBack is for page load, not button clicks.

Comment: make sure you form is passing the validation also

Comment: @MethodMan I tried the breakpoint on the line you point out, it goes through. I am confused about the second part you mentioned. could you please give me more information on that? Thanks.

Comment: @DourHighArch Sorry I make you confused. I am not getting any error. So I deploy it on my local machine and try it on Internet Explorer. I open the database found out the table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for postback in the button click. It's probably TRUE not FALSE. Change your method to this. If you see it write out the "postback" string, you need to change your check to IsPostBack instead of !IsPostBack
Also, not sure what Validate() is and I don't see it defined. Might cause an exception. Comment it out if you have problems just to test the insert.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) 
            {
                Validate();
                update(txtFirstName.Text,
                                  txtLastName.Text,
                                  txtEmail.Text,
                                  txtNumber.Text,
                                  DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text,
                                  txtMessage.Text);
                Response.Write("Record was successfully added!");
                //ClearForm(Page);
            } 
            else Response.Write("Postback");
        }
```